# solve E11000 duplicate key error collection: _id_ dup key in pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I am trying to insert a great number of document(+1M) using a bulk_write instruction. In order to do that, I create a list of InsertOne function.

`python version = 3.7.4`

`pymongo version = 3.8.0`

Document creation:

```
document = {
    'dictionary': ObjectId(dictionary_id),
    'price': price,
    'source': source,
    'promo': promo,
    'date': now_utc,
    'updatedAt': now_utc,
    'createdAt:': now_utc
  }

# add line to debug
if '_id' in document.keys():
    print(document)

return document
```

I create the full list of document by adding a new field from a list of elements and create the query by using InsertOne

```
bulk = []
for element in list_elements:
    for document in documents:
        document['new_field'] = element
        # add line to debug
        if '_id' in document.keys():
           print(document)
        insert = InsertOne(document)
        bulk.append(insert)
return bulk
```

I  do the insert by using `bulk_write` command

```
collection.bulk_write(bulk, ordered=False)
```

I attach the documentation https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.bulk_write

According to the documentation,the `_id` field is added automatically
`Parameter - document: The document to insert. If the document is missing an _id field one will be added.`

And somehow it seems that is doing it wrong because some of them have the same value.
Receiving this error(with differents _id of course) for 700k of the 1M documents
`'E11000 duplicate key error collection: database.collection index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId(\'5f5fccb4b6f2a4ede9f6df62\') }'`
Seems a bug to me from pymongo, because I used this approach in many situations but I didn't with such size of documents

The `_id` field has to be unique for sure, but, due to this is done automatically by pymongo, I don't know how to approach to this problem, perhaps using a UpdateOne with upsert True with an impossible filter and hope for the best.

I would appreciate any solution or work around for this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that as I was adding the new field of the document and append it into the list, I created similar instances of the same element, so I had the same queries `len(list_elements)` times and that is why I had the duplicated key error.

to solve the problem, I append to the list a copy of the document

```
bulk.append(document.copy())
```

and then create the queries with that list

I would like to thank @Belly Buster for his help in the issue

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. You can accept your own answer so that other know it's resolved.

Comment: thanks, I can't accepted yet, I have to wait 13 hours T.T, but I will when possible

Comment: thanks, @CapiHidalgo it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

If any of the `documents` from your code snippet already contain an `_id`, a new one won't be added, and you run the risk of getting a duplicate error as you have observed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but in the definition of those documents there is not any field ``_id``

Comment: Firstly, are you absolutely sure? If you are, we will need to see more code, i.e. how documents are created and the command that processes `bulk`. Also post your python and pymongo versions.

Comment: Humour me. Add a debug line `if '_id' in document: print(document)` in your inner loop.

Comment: I added the code and version on the original question and right now I am debugging using the line you suggested, I'll update as soon as it finish

Comment: I just run the program with the  debugging line you suggested and it didn't find any document with '_id' in its keys before create the InsertOne query

Comment: I'll grant you it does seem odd. If there's no `_id` in the document then `InsertOne` should not give a duplicate error on the insert. Could I point you towards a couple of things to try. Firstly check how you are handling retryable writes. Secondly consider using an ordererd bulk operation.

Comment: In regard to use an orderer bulk operation, you are right, that is how I tried in the first place, I just tried the unordered to see if it was a problem of just one document. Nonetheless, I have realized  that, even though I have 3 elements in my list, when I am filling my new field, in each loop somehow the elements in my list are rewrited with the last element of the list, which seems extremely  weird to me, I am trying a different approach to fill my queries to see if all of them are set correctly. Anyway, it shouldn't fill the ``_id`` with the same value